# i cant get the exactly location in my application

Tags: android, kotlin

when i select a contact to get there location in my app it show a map with icon of location but in the middle of the map not in reel location so thats the code in MainActivity :

```
    fun getUserLocation() {
var myLocation = MyLocationListener()
val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3, 3f, myLocation)

//list sent to request
var userData=UserData(this)
val myPhoneNumber=userData.loadPhoneNumber()
databaseRef!!.child("Users").child(myPhoneNumber).child("request").addValueEventListener(
    object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
            if (MainActivity.myLocation==null) return
            //get datatime
            val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss")
            val date = Date()

           databaseRef!!.child("Users").child(myPhoneNumber).child("location").child("lat").setValue(MainActivity.myLocation!!.latitude)
           databaseRef!!.child("Users").child(myPhoneNumber).child("location").child("log").setValue(MainActivity.myLocation!!.longitude)
           databaseRef!!.child("Users").child(myPhoneNumber).child("location").child("lastOnline").setValue(df.format(date).toString())

        }
```

and that's the URL of my Full application help me please
https://files.fm/u/xnrm88u7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get you coordination from callback listener.

So put you list send request inside location listener:

```
   inner class MyLocationListener: LocationListener {

                     constructor():super(){
                     AccesLocation=true
                     myLocation= Location("me")
                     myLocation?.longitude=0.0
                     myLocation?.latitude=0.0
                     }

                     override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
                         myLocation=location

                      //list sent to request
    var userData=UserData(this)
    val myPhoneNumber=userData.loadPhoneNumber()
    databaseRef?.child("Users").child(myPhoneNumber).child("request").addValueEventListener(
        object :ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
                if (MainActivity.myLocation==null) return
                //get datatime
                val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:ss")
                val date = Date()

               databaseRef?.child("Users").child(myPhoneNumber).child("location").child("lat").setValue(loction?.latitude)
               databaseRef?.child("Users").child(myPhoneNumber).child("location").child("log").setValue(loction?.longitude)
               databaseRef?.child("Users").child(myPhoneNumber).child("location").child("lastOnline").setValue(df.format(date).toString())

            } 

                     }

...
};
```

And try to use **?** insted **!!**

Comment: please open my project i put URL in the question and change what should be changed please